# Excel Date Formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 3 cells in Excel as follows:

Cell

> A1=2012
>     A2=12
>     A3=15

Which contains year, month & date value respectively. And I want to make a date string out of it.

I know it's very easy to achieve using `Date` function. 
But I also want the cell to remain blank if any of A1,A2 or A3 is blank.

Comment: I future pls note basic formulae questions are better suited to Super User

Comment: @brettdj: You are right. But I asked same question there & no response yet. http://superuser.com/questions/475751/excel-date-formula-with-a-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

`=IF(COUNT(A1:A3)=3,DATE(A1,A2,A3),"")`